# Discover test failing in VS Express 2013 for Web

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I hope somebody can help because I have this recurrent issue with my VS Express 2013 for Web project that is preventing me from running any unit tests.

When I build my solution, the test output window displays the following:

```
------ Discover test started ------
The system cannot find the file specified
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.0678182) ==========
```

I have several Visual Studio tests in the solution, and at one point this was working fine.

I would upload a sample project, but I tried creating a brand new solution and the same thing happened so this is something to do with the environment.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Express 2013 for Web, with no luck.

This has worked in the past, and I did somehow get it back to working at some point but it's been like this for the last 5-10 times I've run VS and tried to run the unit tests.

Does anybody have any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can't you open the Test Explorer window? That will tell you which tests are failing

Comment: There are no tests in the Test Explorer window. The Discover Test process is failing when I build the solution.

Comment: Do you have any deployment files or folders?